# How to scale database service in Cloudfoundry?

Tags: database, scalability, cloud-foundry

I'd like to know how to scale database service in Cloudfoundry properly. As for know I've come up with two potential approaches and I need to know which one is right (or maybe neither of them).

1. Deploy a database cluster outside CF and bind it to the application as a user-provided service
2. Bind several service instances to the application and somehow switch between them. I'm not sure that it makes sense, however.

UPD: I'm using open source Cloudfoundry distribution, so I can't use any of products that are intended for usage with Pivotal Cloud foundry distribution.

Any help on this matter will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you asking this question from CF user perspective (or) CF provider perspective ?

Comment: @vmovva from provider's perspective

Comment: Hi Mikhail, were you able to solve this? If you were able to you might want to answer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450398/how-to-scale-a-database-at-runtime-make-database-available-as-a-service-over

Comment: @kaulmonish unfortunately I wasn't able to come to any working solution

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create or use a service that explicitly supports clustering and replication.

For example, Pivotal distributes a HA version of the MySQL service that allows you to decide how many instances/VMs to provision in your cluster:

https://network.pivotal.io/products/p-mysql

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I use CF's open source release, such services won't fit for me, AFAIK. Is there any alternative?